# Remove characters from C# string not belonging to a specicif code page

Tags: c#, string, codepages

In C# I have a string that goes on to be inserted into a db table using codepage 37 US. So for instance, the '€' will cause the insert operation to fail.

What is a good way to clean my string of characters not represented in code page 37 and possible replace those charaters with some default character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
        var euroString = "abc?€./*";
        var encoding37 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(
            37, 
            new EncoderReplacementFallback("_"), //replacement char
            new DecoderExceptionFallback());
        var byteArrayWithFallbackChars = encoding37.GetBytes(euroString);
        var utfStringFromBytesWithFallback = new string(encoding37.GetChars(byteArrayWithFallbackChars));
        //returns "abc?_./*"
```

P.S.: you can just use `GetEncoding(37)`, but in this case replacement char is `?` which I think is not really OK for DB :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex to restrict input to a range of allowed characters:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WIrSSO

```
const string Allowed = @"1-9\."; //Add allowed chars here
string cleanStr = Regex.Replace("£1.11", "[^" + Allowed + "]", "");
```